# Get all directly intermediate and ultimate parent nodes of a child node in a pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe with parent child relationships that looks like this:

> ```
> **child                Parent              relationship**
>
>    A1x2                 bc11                direct_parent
>    bc11                 Aw00                direct_parent
>    bc11                 Aw00                ultimate_parent
>    Aee1                 Aee0                direct_parent
>    Aee1                 Aee0                ultimate_parent
> ```

I would like to get all the ancestors for all  child nodes in a new dataframe. The result would look something like this:

> ```
> node                   ancesstory_tree
>
> A1x2                    [A1x2,bc11,Aw00]   
> Aee1                    [Aee1,Aee0]
> ```

Note: The real dataset could have a lot of direct predecessor nodes between child and ultimate parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach, using the [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html) and [`ancestors`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.ancestors.html) from the [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/) package:

```
import networkx as nx

# Create the Directed Graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,
                            source='Parent',
                            target='child',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph())

# Create dict of nodes and ancestors
ancestors = {n: {n} | nx.ancestors(G, n) for n in df['child'].unique()}

# Convert dict back to DataFrame if necessary
df_ancestors = pd.DataFrame([(k, list(v)) for k, v in ancestors.items()],
                            columns=['node', 'ancestry_tree'])

print(df_ancestors)
```

[out]

```
   node       ancestry_tree
0  A1x2  [A1x2, Aw00, bc11]
1  bc11        [bc11, Aw00]
2  Aee1        [Aee1, Aee0]
```

---

To filter out "middle children" from the output table, you can filter to last children only using the [`out_degree`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.out_degree.html) method - where last children should have an out_degree  `== 0`

```
last_children = [n for n, d in G.out_degree() if d == 0]

ancestors = {n: {n} | nx.ancestors(G, n) for n in last_children}

df_ancestors = pd.DataFrame([(k, list(v)) for k, v in ancestors.items()],
                            columns=['node', 'ancestry_tree'])
```

[out]

```
   node       ancestry_tree
0  A1x2  [A1x2, Aw00, bc11]
1  Aee1        [Aee1, Aee0]
```

Comment: Thankyou, this solution is more understandable to me but I get an error when creating dict of nodes and ancestors: 

NetworkXError: The node xvr00001 is not in the graph.

Comment: @MuhammadAliZia feel free to upvote the answer as well if you find it useful.

Comment: @MuhammadAliZia, what happens if you don't filter the into DataFrame to the "from_edgelist" method.. ie `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Parent', target='child', create_using=nx.DiGraph())`

Comment: I've noticed that in some cases the child node appears at the end or middle of the ancestry tree like this:

A1x2  [Aw00, bc11, A1x2]
A11c  [An21, A11c,bb2]

Comment: @MuhammadAliZia if this has answered your question, please consider clicking the check mark to select this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

- Create a dictionary of relationships
- Step through each `child` that is not also a `parent`
- Track the ancestry path as well as a `set` of descendants

  - This is important because we want to terminate the while loop if we run into a node that has already been seen

---

```
relate = dict(zip(df.child, df.Parent))
paths = {}
nodes = {}
for child in cp.keys() - {*cp.values()}:
    paths[child] = [child]
    nodes[child] = {child}
    parent = relate[child]
    while parent in relate and parent not in nodes[child]:
        paths[child].append(parent)
        nodes[child].add(parent)
        parent = relate[parent]
    paths[child].append(parent)

pd.Series(paths).rename_axis('node').reset_index(name='ancestry_tree')


   node       ancestry_tree
0  Aee1        [Aee1, Aee0]
1  A1x2  [A1x2, bc11, Aw00]
```

Comment: My original dataframe is quite large(a couple of million rows). I get a memory error at: d[c].append(p)

Comment: Oh!  the memory footprint shouldn't be an issue... unless you have a cycle in your network that makes it recursive.... Hmmm, let me figure that out.